# How to store the output in excel from docker python arithmetic program

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I need to run a simple arithmetic program using python into the docker, and it displays the output in excel?

```py
# Python Program to Perform Arithmetic Operations
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd 

num1 = float(input(" Please Enter the First Value Number 1: "))
num2 = float(input(" Please Enter the Second Value Number 2: "))

# Add Two Numbers
add = num1 + num2

# Subtracting num2 from num1
sub = num1 - num2

# Multiply num1 with num2
multi = num1 * num2

# Divide num1 by num2
div = num1 / num2

# Modulus of num1 and num2
mod = num1 % num2

# Exponent of num1 and num2
expo = num1 ** num2

print("The Sum of {0} and {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, add))
print("The Subtraction of {0} from {1} = {2}".format(num2, num1, sub))
print("The Multiplication of {0} and {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, multi))
print("The Division of {0} and {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, div))
print("The Modulus of {0} and {1} = {2}".format(num1, num2, mod))

preparedList = [num1,num2,add,sub,multi,div,mod]


loc = ('output/maths.xlsx') 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

itemList = []

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    itemList.append(sheet.row_values(i))

itemList.append(preparedList)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(loc)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0

for items in itemList:
    col = 0
    for val in items:
        worksheet.write(row, col, val)
        col = col + 1
    row = row + 1

workbook.close()
```

It shows the below output correctly, but I need to store the output in an Excel sheet.

```
   PS E:\bala\docker-python-app> docker run -it python-app
 Please Enter the First Value Number 1: 45
 Please Enter the Second Value Number 2: 5
The Sum of 45.0 and 5.0 = 50.0
The Subtraction of 5.0 from 45.0 = 40.0
The Multiplication of 45.0 and 5.0 = 225.0
The Division of 45.0 and 5.0 = 9.0
The Modulus of 45.0 and 5.0 = 0.0
```

Comment: can you please check if its work with you dear @aravind

Comment: it is working good. but I need to store the output excel. I mentioned excel sheet path correctly but I am not able to store. please provide your suggestions @Adiii

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the image with the command like below:

```
docker run -it image
```

Image will be started in interactive mode with terminal.

More useful information can be found by link below:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention `-it` for interactive mode.starts the container in the interactive mode (`hence -it flag`) that allows you to interact with `/bin/bash` or `/bin/ash` of the container.

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine3.10
    RUN echo $'#!/usr/bin/python \n\
    num1 = float(input(\" Please Enter the First Value Number 1: \")) \n\
    num2 = float(input(\" Please Enter the Second Value Number 2: \")) \n\
    # Add Two Numbers \n\
    add = num1 + num2 \n\
    sub = num1 - num2 \n\
    multi = num1 * num2 \n\
    # Divide num1 by num2 \n\
    div = num1 / num2 \n\
    # Modulus of num1 and num2 \n\
    mod = num1 % num2 \n\
    # Exponent of num1 and num2 \n\
    expo = num1 ** num2 \n\
    print(\"The Sum of {0} and {1} = {2}\".format(num1, num2, add)) ' >> /root/ab.py

    CMD [ "python" , "/root/ab.py"]
```

Now build the image

```
docker build -t pyinput .
```

Run the Container

```
docker run --rm -it pyinput
```

[image]

**Update:**

docker run command

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/output:/output pyinput ash -c "python /root/ab.py"
```

Mount the directory so you will see the output on host machine.
Here is the complete example, I am just adding one value, do rest for your self

```
FROM python:3.7.4-alpine3.10
RUN  mkdir -p /output
RUN touch /output/maths.xlsx
RUN  pip install xlsxwriter xlrd
RUN pip install xlwt
RUN echo $'#!/usr/bin/python \n\
import xlsxwriter \n\
import xlrd \n\
import xlwt \n\
from xlwt import Workbook \n\
num1 = float(input(\" Please Enter the First Value Number 1: \")) \n\
num2 = float(input(\" Please Enter the Second Value Number 2: \")) \n\
# Add Two Numbers \n\
add = num1 + num2 \n\
sub = num1 - num2 \n\
multi = num1 * num2 \n\
# Divide num1 by num2 \n\
div = num1 / num2 \n\
# Modulus of num1 and num2 \n\
mod = num1 % num2 \n\
# Exponent of num1 and num2 \n\
expo = num1 ** num2 \n\
print(\"The Sum of {0} and {1} = {2}\".format(num1, num2, add)) \n\
preparedList = [num1,num2,add,sub,multi,div,mod] \n\
wb = Workbook() \n\  
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet(\'Sheet 1\') \n\
sheet1.write(1, 0, \'Add\') \n\
sheet1.write(0, 1, \'Add\') \n\
sheet1.write(1, 1, add) \n\
wb.save(\'/output/xlwt example.xls\') \n\
print ( \"Entries saved to /output/xlwt example.xls\")' >> /root/ab.py
CMD [ "python" , "/root/ab.py"]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: let me know if there any issue

Comment: still i am not able to show the output in excel.but there is no error in run a docker @Adiii

Comment: Which os your are using

Comment: i am using windows 10

Comment: It will run, generate an exel file and  then  exit

Comment: it will give an exact output in PowerShell but I can't store the data in excel.

Comment: do you have set permission for the directory, mean shared your drive with docker, I am on linux, so i can debug with window. what is the error with the above docker image can you please share

Comment: PS E:\bala\docker-python-app> docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/output:/output python-app ash -c "app.py"
python3: can't open file 'ash': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: first buid my posted image.
`docker build -t pyinput  .`

docker run command

`docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/output:/output pyinput ash -c "python /root/ab.py"`

Comment: My build command PS E:\bala\docker-python-app> docker build -t python-app .   my run command
PS E:\bala\docker-python-app> docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/output:/output python-app ash -c "app.py"
python3: can't open file 'ash': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: ash denotes wt? i dont know?

Comment: ash is used for alpine based image.

Comment: you need to read about docker, docker run, docker build and alpine. you mess every thing, you have build image from the above image, if you need further assistence ping of https://www.linkedin.com/in/adiiim/ here. we will help u remotly

Comment: I need to read docker from basics.. please suggest the tutorials name.